# Отправка последнего ajax запроса если в течении 2-х сек не было нажатий клавиши

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Допустим, есть товар, при нажатии пользователем кнопки Добавить в корзину, на сервер отправляется ajax запрос, что этот товар добавляется, либо, что этот товар поменял количество, тогда в запросе будет ещё и количество.

Вопрос в чём, пользователь 100 раз нажал на кнопку добавления товара, но сервер отработал только, скажем, 64 запроса. Визуально, у нас в корзине 100 товаров, фактически 64 товара, после перезагрузки будет видно фактическое количество.

Можно ли как-то отследить интервал между нажатиями и если пользователь перестал нажимать на кнопку в течении 2-х секунд, то отправить последний запрос, обрезав остальные?

UPD: Прошу не предлагать использовать другой способ добавления, обработки запроса и т.д. Спасибо.

Comment: обновляйте количество товаров в корзине после успешного получения ответа от сервера а не в момент отправки запроса

Comment: @torokhkun вопрос был не про то как обрабатывать запрос.

Comment: Кажется, тут идеально подходит debounce.  Он как раз, ждёт указанный таймаут и если больше вызовов не было - вызывает последнее обращение. Например, реализацию debounce можно посмотреть в lodash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var timer = null;
$(".button").click(function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("2 seconds of no clicking");
    timer = null;
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button">Click</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо. То, что надо!

Answer (score 2):

Чуть опоздал с ответом, но не удалять же написанное.

```js
let lastfn,
timer
$('button').click(()=>{
  lastfn=()=>{
    //здесь можете разместить ваш аякс запрос
    alert('FINALLY YOU STOP IT! >_<')
  }
  timer&&clearTimeout(timer)
  timer=setTimeout(lastfn,2000)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>PRESS ME ^_^</button>
```

Comment: Что-то впервые вижу такой синтаксис как `$('button').click(()=>{` Можете объяснить?

Comment: @DrummerIF https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function#%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7  - "запись через стрелочку"